# Filter my @html.dropdownlistfor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, filtering, html.dropdownlistfor

Im working with a project and i need to filter my second dropdownlistfor based on my first dropdownlistfor value. Its simple to understand but hard to code it since i dont know jquery or javascript and im working in mvc asp.net, aswell as using a database in sql server where the data is located.

I need to filter my dropdown for project based on my dropdown for customer.

here is some of the code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>TimeEntry</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Customer")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TimeEntry.CustomerId, @customerSelectList)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TimeEntry.CustomerId)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Project")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TimeEntry.ProjectId, @projectSelectList, "[ - No project - ]")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TimeEntry.ProjectId)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}


public IEnumerable<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<Project> Projects { get; set; }
```

here is a code which i think is the code that is calling from the database but not really sure:

```
var customers = service.GetAllCustomers().ToList();
model.Customers = new SelectList(customers, "CustomerId", "Name");
var projects = service.GetAllProjects().ToList();
model.Projects = new SelectList(projects, "ProjectId", "Name");
```

Comment: Where is the lisitems for the second dropdown be coming from? Are you planning to call a controller method (which only make sense)?

Comment: @von v forgot the code for the model, its updated now

Comment: I'm afraid that won't help. How do you plan to do the filtering? Through some ajax call right? So you can have a controller method say `GetProjects` that accepts an int for the `customerId` and then you query your database and return a json result that you can consume on the client and build your project dropdownlist, is that similar to the approach you're thinking?

Comment: @von v, yh its similar, ive been looking through jq, js, ajax and jason but i havent found a good example that i can use which i understand. i can use any calling methods whatsoever as long as it works

Comment: @von v did another edit to the question, found another code in one of the controllers, which i think calls from the database

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you have a controller with a method that gives you the filtered projects like so:

```
public class FilterController:Controller {
    public ActionResult Projects(int customerId) {
        // I expect this call to be filtered
        // so I'll leave this to you on how you want this filtered       
        var projects = service.GetAllProjects().ToList();
        // at this point, projects should already be filtered with "customerId"
        return Json(new SelectList(projects, "ProjectId", "Name"),                
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Then you call that method on the client like this:

```
// when the customer dropdown changes, you want to use the selected value
// and filter the projects dropdown - more like refresh it
$("#TimeEntry_CustomerId").change(function(){
    refreshProjects($(this).val());
});
function refreshProjects(id) {
    var projects = $("#TimeEntry_ProjectId");
    $.get('@Url.Action("projects","filter")', {customerId:id}, 
        function (result) {
            // clear the dropdown
            projects.empty();
            // rebuild the dropdown
            $.each(result, function (i, e) {
                projects.append($('<option/>').text(e.Text).val(e.Value));
            });                
    });            
}
```

Comment: v ive been looking at it and tried with different solutions but i cant make it work. we dont really under how the function works so we are thinking to leave the issue and send this code to our suporvisor instead, but thanks for your help